# zsh tab completion categories

Tags: shell, zsh, tab-completion

I'm using [this script](http://jarod.wikidot.com/zsh-configuration) to improve my tab completion. When I press <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> it now renders out like this:

[image]

You'll notice it spits out the type of completion at the top.

I don't think the categories/types are all supposed to lumped up at the top though; I think each of the commands should be below their respective category. Can I customize zsh to do this? How?

I must admit I don't know which of those `zstyle` commands is causing this behaviour. I'll paste the relevant bit of the script below in case the link goes down:

```
# Completion caching
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' use-cache on
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' cache-path .zcache
zstyle ':completion:*:cd:*' ignore-parents parent pwd

#Completion Options
zstyle ':completion:*:match:*' original only
zstyle ':completion::prefix-1:*' completer _complete
zstyle ':completion:predict:*' completer _complete
zstyle ':completion:incremental:*' completer _complete _correct
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _prefix _correct _prefix _match _approximate

# Path Expansion
zstyle ':completion:*' expand 'yes'
zstyle ':completion:*' squeeze-shlashes 'yes'
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' '\\'

zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:default' menu yes select
zstyle ':completion:*:*:default' force-list always

# GNU Colors 需要/etc/DIR_COLORS文件 否则自动补全时候选菜单中的选项不能彩色显示
[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ] && eval $(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)
export ZLSCOLORS="${LS_COLORS}"
zmodload  zsh/complist
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*:processes' list-colors '=(#b) #([0-9]#)*=0=01;31' 

zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _match _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*:match:*' original only
zstyle ':completion:*:approximate:*' max-errors 1 numeric

compdef pkill=kill
compdef pkill=killall
zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*' menu yes select
zstyle ':completion:*:processes' command 'ps -au$USER'

# Group matches and Describe
zstyle ':completion:*:matches' group 'yes'
zstyle ':completion:*:options' description 'yes'
zstyle ':completion:*:options' auto-description '%d'
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format $'\e[01;33m -- %d --\e[0m'
zstyle ':completion:*:messages' format $'\e[01;35m -- %d --\e[0m'
zstyle ':completion:*:warnings' format $'\e[01;31m -- No Matches Found --\e[0m'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
```

Comment: Do I just add that anywhere, or does it replace something?

Comment: Just add it. You can even colorize different groups defferently like **zstyle ':completion:*:commands' list-colors '=*=1;32'**